# Play button to pause button

Tags: javascript, html, css

What do I need to do with this CSS if I want the **play button** to change into this **pause button**: `<i class='material-icons'>pause</i>` on click and play a sound. Then if I click on the **pause button**, change it back to a **play button** and **set the specific sound in this box back to 0:00**. If the sound ends, it should automatically switch to a **play button** and **set the sound back to 0:00**.

I want as well if I have for example 2 or more boxes like this every play/stop button will work only for the specific one and not for all of them.

Also can some designer look at that play button and update it to look better, but that isn't the main problem..

```css
.box {
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #f5f5f5);
    padding: 16px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    position: relative;

}

.box_title {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom:  1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.box_title i {
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.box_content {
    margin: 0 0 18px 0;
    border-bottom:  1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);
    text-align: justify;
}

.box_footer {
    position:absolute;               
                bottom:-5px;                         
                left:20px;  
    font-size: 14px;

}

.box_footer_right i {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 0 0.3em 0 0.3em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.box_footer_right {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position:absolute;                 
                bottom:-5px;                         
                right:20px;  
}

.playbutton {
    cursor: pointer;
    object-fit: cover;
      border-radius: 50%;
      margin: 1em auto 20px auto;
      display: block;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #f5f5f5);
    width: 125px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    user-select: none;
}

.playbutton:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}

.playbutton:active {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    box-shadow: 0 5px #f5f5f5;
    -webkit-transition: 0s;
    transform: translateY(4px);
}


.playbutton i {
    font-size: 120px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="box">
            <div class="box_title"><i class='material-icons'>graphic_eq</i>Test song title</div>
            <div class="playbutton"><i class='material-icons'>play_arrow</i>  <!-- <i class='material-icons'>pause</i> --></div>
            <div class="box_content">


                <p> Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
                
                <p class="box_footer"> date | autor </p>
                <p class="box_footer_right"> <i class='material-icons'>delete</i> | <i class='material-icons'>edit</i> | <i class='material-icons'>visibility</i></p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: This question needs to be refined a bit. What do you mean by "set the sound back to 0:00". Do you mean that you want the to be set to the beginning? We can't help you with that unless you show an attempt at making music play. This is also not a place where you can ask for graphic design work.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. You need to write some code and if you get stuck, post the code and explain where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Change the code of the css stylesheet to this

```
        .box {
        text-align: center;
        width: 300px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #f5f5f5);
        padding: 16px;
        margin: 0 0 10px 0;
        position: relative;

    }

    .box_title {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        font-weight: bold;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .box_title i {
        padding-right: 10px;
    }


    .box_content {
        margin: 0 0 18px 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);
        text-align: justify;
    }

    .box_footer {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -5px;
        left: 20px;
        font-size: 14px;

    }

    .box_footer_right i {
        font-size: 14px;
        padding: 0 0.3em 0 0.3em;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .box_footer_right {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -5px;
        right: 20px;
    }

    .playbutton {
        cursor: pointer;
        object-fit: cover;
        border-radius: 50%;
        margin: 1em auto 20px auto;
        display: block;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #f5f5f5);
        width: 125px;
        -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
        user-select: none;
        display: none
    }

    .playbutton.show {
        display: block;
    }

    .playbutton:hover {
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    }

    .playbutton:active {
        background: #f5f5f5;
        box-shadow: 0 5px #f5f5f5;
        -webkit-transition: 0s;
        transform: translateY(4px);
    }


    .playbutton i {
        font-size: 120px;
    }

    .pausebutton {
        cursor: pointer;
        object-fit: cover;
        border-radius: 50%;
        margin: 1em auto 20px auto;
        display: block;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #f5f5f5);
        width: 125px;
        display: none;
        -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
        user-select: none;
    }

    .pausebutton:hover {
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    }

    .pausebutton:active {
        background: #f5f5f5;
        box-shadow: 0 5px #f5f5f5;
        -webkit-transition: 0s;
        transform: translateY(4px);
    }


    .pausebutton i {
        font-size: 120px;
    }

    .pausebutton.show {
        display: block
    }
```

Change the code of the HTML file to this:

```
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="box">
    <div class="box_title"><i class='material-icons'>graphic_eq</i>Test song title</div>
    <div class="playbutton show" id="play" onclick="hidePlay()"><i class='material-icons'>play_arrow</i>
        <!-- <i class='material-icons'>pause</i> -->
    </div>
    <div class="pausebutton" id="pause" onclick="showPause()"><i class='material-icons'>pause</i></div>
    <!-- <i class='material-icons'>pause</i> -->

    <div class="box_content">


        <p> Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
            Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>

        <p class="box_footer"> date | autor </p>
        <p class="box_footer_right"> <i class='material-icons'>delete</i> | <i class='material-icons'>edit</i> | <i
                class='material-icons'>visibility</i></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and just below the HTML File add this line of code of JavaScript:

```
    <script>
    var play = document.getElementById('play')
    var pause = document.getElementById('pause')
    function showPlay() {
        play.classList.add('show')
        pause.classList.remove('show')
        play.setAttribute('onclick', 'hidePlay()');
    }
    function showPause() {
        pause.classList.add('show')
        play.classList.remove('show')
        pause.setAttribute('onclick', 'hidePause()');
    }
    function hidePlay() {
        pause.classList.add('show')
        play.classList.remove('show')
        pause.setAttribute('onclick', 'showPlay()');
    }
    function hidePause() {
        pause.classList.remove('show')
        play.classList.add('show')
        pause.setAttribute('onclick', 'showPause()');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This is just for switching from play to pause and pause to play

Answer (score 1):

With the Sound Version keep the css stylesheet code same:

```
    .box {
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #f5f5f5);
    padding: 16px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    position: relative;

}

.box_title {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.box_title i {
    padding-right: 10px;
}


.box_content {
    margin: 0 0 18px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);
    text-align: justify;
}

.box_footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -5px;
    left: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;

}

.box_footer_right i {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 0 0.3em 0 0.3em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.box_footer_right {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -5px;
    right: 20px;
}

.playbutton {
    cursor: pointer;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 1em auto 20px auto;
    display: block;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #f5f5f5);
    width: 125px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    user-select: none;
    display: none
}

.playbutton.show {
    display: block;
}

.playbutton:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}

.playbutton:active {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    box-shadow: 0 5px #f5f5f5;
    -webkit-transition: 0s;
    transform: translateY(4px);
}


.playbutton i {
    font-size: 120px;
}

.pausebutton {
    cursor: pointer;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 1em auto 20px auto;
    display: block;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #f5f5f5);
    width: 125px;
    display: none;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    user-select: none;
}

.pausebutton:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}

.pausebutton:active {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    box-shadow: 0 5px #f5f5f5;
    -webkit-transition: 0s;
    transform: translateY(4px);
}


.pausebutton i {
    font-size: 120px;
}

.pausebutton.show {
    display: block
}
```

But in HTML change the code a little bit:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"                rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? family=Nunito:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="box">
<audio id="myAudio" src="your-sound-file-name" onended="showPlay()"></audio>
<div class="box_title"><i class='material-icons'>graphic_eq</i>Test song title</div>
<div class="playbutton show" id="play" onclick="hidePlay()"><i class='material-icons'>play_arrow</i>
    <!-- <i class='material-icons'>pause</i> -->
</div>
<div class="pausebutton" id="pause" onclick="showPause()"><i class='material-icons'>pause</i></div>
<!-- <i class='material-icons'>pause</i> -->

<div class="box_content">


    <p> Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
        Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>

    <p class="box_footer"> date | autor </p>
    <p class="box_footer_right"> <i class='material-icons'>delete</i> | <i class='material-icons'>edit</i> | <i
            class='material-icons'>visibility</i></p>
</div>
```

And Below it change the JavaScript Code:

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("myAudio");
var duration = document.getElementById("myAudio").duration;
var play = document.getElementById('play')
var pause = document.getElementById('pause')
function showPlay() {
    play.classList.add('show')
    pause.classList.remove('show')
    x.pause()
    play.setAttribute('onclick', 'hidePlay()');
}
function showPause() {
    pause.classList.add('show')
    play.classList.remove('show')
    pause.setAttribute('onclick', 'hidePause()');
}
function hidePlay() {
    pause.classList.add('show')
    play.classList.remove('show')
    x.play()
    pause.setAttribute('onclick', 'showPlay()');
}
function hidePause() {
    pause.classList.remove('show')
    play.classList.add('show')
    pause.setAttribute('onclick', 'showPause()');
}
</script>
```